# Guice inject cached or non-cached implementation

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have an application with guice but **without spring**.
I have:

```
public interface Service {
   int square(int i);
}
```

And i have 2 implementations:

```
public class NormalService implements Service {
   @Override
   public int square(int i) {
       return i * i;
   }
}

public class CachedService implements Service {
   private final Service service;

   @Inject
   public CachedService(@Named("service") Service service) {
       this.service = service;
   }

   @Override
   public int square(int i) {
       return cache.get(i, () -> i * i);
   }
}

bind(NormalService.class).to(Service.class).named("service");
bind(CachedService.class).to(Service.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

I want to be able to inject cached service to every other service and i want to inject normal service in cached service. The problem is that when i want to inject Service interface in other classes implementation is chosen randomly. Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [named bindings](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/guice/guice_named_binding.htm) with `@Named` annotation to specify exactly which bean do you want to be injected.

Specify the name of the bean you want injected.

```
@Inject @Named("DefaultService")
MyService service;
```

And then you also supply the name in the binding ...

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(MysService.class)
      .annotatedWith(Names.named("DefaultService"))
      .to(MyServiceDefaultImpl.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes are permuted in bindings. Should be

```
bind(Service.class).to(NormalService.class).named("service");
bind(Service.class).to(CachedService.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

Of course, `.named(…)` won't work, see Arthur's answer for solution.